# HLSL min16float fails to compile

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl

I have a shader:

```
float4 Test_PixelShader(float2 inTex:TEXCOORD,
                uniform int    mode          ):COLOR
{
   if(mode) // half
   {
      min16float2 t=(min16float2)inTex;
      min16float2 r=1;
      for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
      {
         r+=t*r;
      }
      return float4(r.x, r.y, mode, 1);
   }else
   {
      float2 t=inTex;
      float2 r=1;
      for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
      {
         r+=t*r;
      }
      return float4(r.x, r.y, mode, 1);
   }
}
#define TECHNIQUE5(name, vs, ps)   technique11 name{pass p0{SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, vs)); SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, ps));}}
TECHNIQUE5(Test , Draw_VertexShader(), Test_PixelShader(0));
TECHNIQUE5(Test1, Draw_VertexShader(), Test_PixelShader(1));
```

Which I'm compiling using:

```
#define FLAGS_DX11    (D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY|D3DCOMPILE_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL3|D3DCOMPILE_NO_PRESHADER)
D3DCompile(data.data(), data.elms(), null, d3d_macros.data(), &Include11(src), null, "fx_5_0", FLAGS_DX11, 0, &buffer, &error);
```

Compilation fails, and the only error message I get is:

> warning X4717: Effects deprecated for D3DCompiler_47

No errors, just a warning, yet the shader blob is null.

However if I replace all `min16float2` with `float2`, then compilation works OK.

How to get `min16float` working?

I've read the https://gpuopen.com/first-steps-implementing-fp16/ article, and it mentions it should work OK.

Do I need to use https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler instead of `D3DCompile` from Win10SDK?

I have Windows 10, using latest Windows SDK

Comment: You should inspect result of D3DCompile invocation.

Comment: I did and the result message is already included in my post.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and ask that in your code, you are testing for support in the driver?   As this is limited to specific AMD hardware, and the recommendation on the page suggests that you do not use it directly in your code, but rather through a pre-processor directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it fails because Microsoft abandoned "fx_*" targets, and have to use "vs/ps" targets instead.